# VSCode shortcuts in macOS changed for no apparent reason

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

My VSCode shortcuts changed, no idea why. They used to match what they are supposed to be according to this:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

But know most of them changed. For instance:

**Toggle sidebar visibility:** was (⌘B), now is (⌘NumPad9).

Some other commands that changed are: Rename, Open/Hide terminal.

[image]

I googled all I could and didn't find a solution or at least the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there an extension changed my shortcuts. I don't remember installing it, maybe it was suggested and I accepted it without looking.